# Make the Jlabels' texts get bexond their boxes

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have Jlabels that are embedded in a 5 row and 9 column gridlayout (In the 2nd row I use JLabels).
Here is what it looks like at the code level.

```
equ_panel_2.add(new JLabel(" "));
JLabel jlalpha = new JLabel("Alpha(α)");
jlalpha.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,12));
equ_panel_2.add(jlalpha); 

equ_panel_2.add(new JLabel(" "));

JLabel jlbeta = new JLabel("Beta(β)");
equ_panel_2.add(jlbeta);
jlbeta.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,12));

equ_panel_2.add(new JLabel(" "));

JLabel jlres = new JLabel("Grid Resolution");
jlres.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,12));
equ_panel_2.add(jlres);

equ_panel_2.add(new JLabel(" "));
JLabel jlbreaks = new JLabel("Breaks after calculations");
jlbreaks.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,12));
equ_panel_2.add(jlbreaks);
equ_panel_2.add(new JLabel(" "));
...
equ_panel_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,9,2,0));
```

this is what it looks like in the result (Comboboxes code not shown here but not relevant)

[image: Jlabels]

My question is simply if it is possible to make the labels of the text protrude out of their box to avoid them being hidden by the gridbag constraints (**"Grid Resolution"** and **"Breaks after calculations"**).

Something akin to the "setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);" method For comboboxes

From what i've red I fear that I must change the gridbag contraints to be able to see the text, but I just wanted to be shure if I can just do something to the labels to allow them to overlap outside the boxes.

Comment: A GridLayout will size each cell to fit the text of the largest cell. If there is not enough space to display the text when the frame size is reduce, then you see the "...". There is no way to have the text display outside the bounds of the cell. The solution would be to NOT use a GridLayout. Instead you a `GridBagLayout`. Then each "column" will be resize to fit the size of the largest component in the column. Note your posted code and image don't match. I don't know why you have so much space between is component. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. Yes I was thinking of using a gridbaglayout, but I thought maybe there would be a trick :)